# Use of now when there is no clear "immediacy purpose"

Tags: grammar

I know the direct usage of the word now when it pertains to something that is happening in a specific moment of the present (the very present you can say). But what about other situations?. I was writing this essay and I wrote this :

Whereas in the past books were the main source of knowledge, the arrival of the internet has drastically altered the relevance of books, because of the easiness in which such information can ***now*** be accessed.

And also this part:

For example, now it is possible to press a button and obtain information that is not only written but also visual and auditive.

Is the usage of the word "now" in the above sentences appropriate?

I think that in both cases "nowadays" can replace "now" and be accurate and correct, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/now

Answer (score 1):

You can replace **now** in both of your sentences and they will still have the same meaning because the usage of your **now** in the context means "recently upto this moment".
However, when you just want to use **now** for the meaning "at the moment and this moment only" then **nowadays** is not the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The use of *now* in these examples is meant to compare the present to the past:

> *Whereas in the past books were the main source of knowledge, the arrival of the internet has drastically altered the relevance of books, because of the easiness in which such information can now **(unlike 30 years ago)** be accessed.*
>
> *For example, now **(unlike 30 years ago)** it is possible to press a button and obtain information that is not only written but also visual and auditive.*

Nowadays would fit in the second example, but not the first (non-colloquial construction).